# How do I prevent Excel from appending extra “” marks when I convert the excel file to a CSV file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I am currently using `=concatenate()` to wrap all my fields in `""` so that it is easier for me to parse in JavaScript after I convert the file to CSV.

The problem is that the actual value in excel is `"test"` but when converted to CSV, it is `"""test"""` or `""""test"""` or `"""test""""`, depending on the position of the cell.

How can I prevent Excel from adding additional quotes when I convert the file to CSV?

Comment: [reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808511/properly-escape-a-double-quote-in-csv) may be useful

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps to save it:

1. Click on File
2. Select "Save As"
3. Selec the folder where you need to save your document
4. Select "Save as type", Click on the dropdown arrow to choose the new format, e.g.,  CSV file (UTF-8)  Comma delimited.
   You can also refer to those links to see if useful:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Excel/Save-as-CSV-file-UTF-8-with-double-quotes-how/td-p/223484

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/export-text-file-with-comma-quote